# Trinomial Regression Issues in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression

In my work with R, I have previously built a binomial regression model and am now being asked to derive how "intervention2" improves my dependent variable "test". My previous model dealt with "intervention1" which was a simple binomial model (0, 1). "intervention2" however has the conditions (0, 1, 2) and I'm not sure if it's valid to just use my same model but using "intervention2" instead (I suspect it's not).
Intervention1 model plotted:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = test, y = intervention1, group = 1)) + 
       geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Intervention1

[image]

Intervention2 model plotted using basically the same model:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = test, y = intervention2, group = 1)) + 
      geom_point() + geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

Intervention2

[image]

Is this just me making nonsense graphs? Is there a way to do this that I don't know? Or is my seemingly too-easy solution actually a stroke of genius? Thanks :)